# Saving appended arrays to NSUserdefaults not returning appended array

Tags: arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I want to save data to a array of dictionaries via NSUSerdefult.

Every time user runs the app I would like to append details to the already existing array of dictionaries in NSUSerdefaults.

Problem is data is not appending to array, as the array.count is always 1, so the one result is always overridden and not appending to existing array in NSUSerdefults.

```
// Instance var
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();

// Array to save to NSUserdef
deaultScoreResults  = [Dictionary<String, String>]();

// Save to NSUSer
deaultScoreResults.append(["CaseResult":caseNumberString+"/Study Up!"])

defaults.setObject(deaultScoreResults, forKey: "userScoreForCase");

// Retrieve in a diff vc
if let scoreValueArray : [Dictionary<String, String>]  = defaults.objectForKey("userScoreForCase") as? Array{


            for dict_Result in scoreValueArray{....
```

Maybe user defaults is not most suitable method for saving appended data to existing data or would core data be more approbate here?

Any input appreciated

Comment: I just tested your code and it works ok (see [screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s89/sh/fceaa5c8-17e7-4e7c-962c-4ed4f3ba1525/19a2d09205aad74770765f7b3d463f5c/deep/0/mnvknbhvkhv.playground---Edited.png)). I guess your problem comes from something else. Maybe your `deaultScoreResults` array is being modified elsewhere before it is saved?

Comment: Every time the app runs the array is declared: // Array to save to NSUserdef
deaultScoreResults  = [Dictionary<String, String>]();
Will this override the stored array in NSUserdeaults? The NSUserdefault ref and array are created in one class, and then accessed in another...

Comment: Looks like it's indeed a problem with the order of your initialization sequence, but I can't help without knowing the architecture of your app. Your usage of NSUserDefaults is ok from what I see in this snippet, the problem is likely to be elsewhere with your array.

Comment: @dancingbush, I updated my answer to provide a doc reference for your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue awhile back, not sure if it was intentional or not. Try casting the dictionary as an NSDictionary before writing it to defaults.

```
defaults.setObject((deaultScoreResults as NSDictionary), forKey: "userScoreForCase");
```

To further elaborate my point, if you look at the apple docs for setting NSUserDefault values you will see that the `value` must be a properly list object: "The value parameter can be only property list objects: NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary" ([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setObject:forKey:)). So performing a cast would solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks, but deaultScoreResults is actually a array holding a dictionary : deaultScoreResults  = [Dictionary<String, String>]();

Comment: Try casting the NSArray, I found (at least in early versions of Swift) that NSUserDefaults could not store Swift objects (native arrays and dictionaries) and I had to caste them all to Objective C classes. You may need to do this recursively.

Comment: @firo There's no need to do this in his case ([screenshot of his code in Playground](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s89/sh/fceaa5c8-17e7-4e7c-962c-4ed4f3ba1525/19a2d09205aad74770765f7b3d463f5c/deep/0/mnvknbhvkhv.playground---Edited.png)).

Comment: This actually further drives my point. The Swift data is all intact. But in his Playground he is never printing out what is actually stored in the defaults, just the local array. So I would guess the array is not being stored properly in the defaults (the playground doesn't reveal otherwise).

Comment: Thanks for the help peoples, it was an issue with initialisation, I was re-intialising and overwritting the array in a diff vc so I only initialisation if it didn't exist in the defaults ref :    if var deaultScoreResults : [Dictionary<String, String>]  = defaults.objectForKey("userScoreForCase") as? Array{.....